# How to change the name of an ArrayController with Xcode 4.0.2 in interface builder

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder

this may sound like an extremely dumb question, but I cannot find the TextField to change my ArrayController's name. And as I have more than 1, it's almost impossible to bind data to them as they are all called the same in the list which gets opened.

So far I changed the Mode to "Entity Name" and "Entity Name" to the model's name in CoreData... i searched through all the available Views..... it's killing me....

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply select arraycontroller at objects list and press 'Enter'